# proximity search in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logical-operators, proximity

How can I use Proximity Search in ElasticSearch Query String

Example Query :

```
(A OR B) **NEAR2** (C OR D)
```

I dont want to use

```
"A C"~2
```

I want this query to get translated to

```
( A Near C ) OR ( A Near D ) OR ( B Near C ) OR ( B Near D )
```

I can only use query string.

Comment: Can you explain why the proximity search syntax ("A C"~2) doesn't work for your case? Why can't you use `"A C"~2 OR "A D"~2 OR "B C"~2 OR "B D"~2`?

Comment: @dshockley 1) I want to use wildcards in proximity, 2) I have just shifted to Elastic, earlier the syntax was a Near b only, so cant change the syntax or tell to the clients. SO what I plan to do is it myself convert it to A B~2 format where the user still enters A near B

Comment: I see. I think you're right, the only thing you can do, is to parse and translate the query. However, the wildcards in proximity search is a bigger problem -- I don't think it's possible. If you have to use elasticsearch, and you need this functionality, I think you'll have to do some clever pre-processing and index an extra field for this purpose, or maybe you can figure out something using ngram or edge ngram tokenizer (depending on your exact needs).